# how to retain value from "get intent" when navigating backwards?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working in Android Studio 2.3.3, and I am using `intent.putExtra` (tied to a `button`) and `getIntent (onCreate)` methods to pass a calculated value from `Activity 1` to `Activity 2`.  While testing, I discovered that when I navigate backwards from `Activity 3` to `Activity 2`, this variable defaults to 0 as coded in `onCreate` method, as one might expect.

```
vol = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("VOL_KEY", 0);
```

I would like to retain this value when I navigate to `Activity 2` backward from `Activity 3`, however.  In the iOS version, I accomplished this functionality with segue methods which seem to work well in both directions.  Is there a way to retain the value passed from `Activity` 1 to 2 on 2 (or `getIntent` from 1 again) so that it will be available for subsequent calculations when I navigate backward to `Activity 2` from `Activity 3`?

Comment: `startActivityForResult`

Answer (score 1):

```
//use Shared Preferences after getting the value from activity one to activity two. In activity two do this.

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("my_sharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putDouble("VOL_KEY", vol);
 editor.apply();
//this will save the value 

//to retrive this value do below

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_sharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
double volValue= prefs.getDouble("VOL_KEY", null);
//in place of null you can use the default value
```

Comment: The .put and .get statements seem to work for floats but not doubles.  This could be on my end since I am using open JDK library that came with Android Studio 2.3.3 install.  I will experiment with floats and see if I can get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

While experimenting with different techniques, I found that adding the following code to the manifest xml file for each activity achieved the desired functionality:

android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
android:launchMode="singleInstance"